# Zend Framework 2, Dynamic Module Configuration

Tags: dynamic, configuration, module, zend-framework2

I am trying to have dynamic module configuration. Imagine situation where you have a table that holds information on what design is to be used. I need to be able to inject a result from this table so I can dynamically specify the paths for view files.

Structure:

index.php
module
--Application
----config
------module.config.php
--Album
--more....
design
--blue
----layouts
----views
------Application
------Album
--default

I need to be able to process the database for the latest design to be used and then use that in the module.config.php so the template paths can use the design folder.

Something like this:

```
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../../../design/'.THEME.'/layouts/layout.phtml',
    'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../../../design/'.THEME.'/views/application/index/index.phtml',
),
'template_path_stack' => array(
    __DIR__ . '/../../../design/'.THEME.'/views',
),
```

But if I use below inside module bootstrap

```
$eventManager->attach('bootstrap', array($this, 'loadThemingConfig'), 100);
```

it will get executed after loading the config file.

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest leave the config with default theme path, something like this:

```
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../../../design/default/layouts/layout.phtml',
    'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../../../design/default/views/application/index/index.phtml',
),
'template_path_stack' => array(
    __DIR__ . '/../../../design/default/views',
),
```

and change it in runtime, you can do that in MVC render event, for example in your Module class:

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver;
use Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function(MvcEvent $event) {
        $sm = $event->getParam('application')->getServiceManager();

        /** @var TemplateMapResolver $viewResolverMap */
        $viewResolverMap = $sm->get('ViewTemplateMapResolver');
        // modify template map

        /** @var TemplatePathStack $viewResolverPathStack */
        $viewResolverPathStack = $sm->get('ViewTemplatePathStack');
        // modify path stack
    }, 10);
}
```